# pivot table(?) with a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is something similar to this

```
id    name    value
a     Adam    5
b     Eve     6
c     Adam    4
a     Eve     3
d     Seth    2
b     Adam    4
a     Adam    2
```

I am trying to see how many `id`s are associated with how many names and the overlap between them. I did a groupby on the id column and then I could see how many id's have how many names associated with them.

```
df.groupby('id')['name'].nunique().value_counts()
```

What I would now like is a way to get a table where the names are the column names, and index is the id, and the value is the sum for each id and name. I could do it for a for loop, by initializing a DataFrame where the columns are the values in the name column but I am wondering if there is a pandas way of accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [54]: df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='name', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
Out[54]:
name  Adam  Eve  Seth
id
a      7.0  3.0   NaN
b      4.0  6.0   NaN
c      4.0  NaN   NaN
d      NaN  NaN   2.0
```

or without NaN's:

```
In [56]: df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='name', values='value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[56]:
name  Adam  Eve  Seth
id
a        7    3     0
b        4    6     0
c        4    0     0
d        0    0     2
```